# udp socket trouble c#

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, udp

I have 2 simple programs in c # using udp connections. The programs both have a client and server to send data back and forth. It works exactly as I Ted when ran at the same time on my laptop, using the ip address as 127.0.0.1

However, when I put one program on another machine, and changed the ip addresses to the specific machines,  it won't work at all. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your firewall ? Another thing to try if you havn't already is ping the ip address and make sure that the port is active. Does The Application run or do you recieve an error ? Could also be a framework issue.

Comment: The application runs on both computers with no errors. I guess I will try to ping the ip addresses. Not sure how to do that,  but Im sure I can Google it. Thank you.

Comment: Start >> Run >> type cmd >> ipconfig / all

Comment: Type "ip configuration / all" ?

Comment: I am sorry that is to get the ip address. You want to type ping 127.0.0 or what ever ip you want to test.

Comment: So on computer 1, type "ping ipcomputer2"  ?

Comment: So when I do this, what am I looking for

Comment: You want to make sure that you have your server application ip address. Once you have that IpAddress you will need to use that you can apply your server endpoint. For Example Your Server is listening on 192.168.0.2 Your Client Application would then need to have the endpoint set to 192.168.0.2

Comment: Great, thanks. Would this give a different ip addresses than if I just Google my ip addresses?

Comment: Yes because the ip address you are wanting is a local address. Google will only show you your ISP's public ip address witch will be the same on every machine actively connected to your router.

Comment: I believe I should be using IPv4 address.  This is the same address google gives though. I can't ping google, however I can ping www.uta.edu, my school website.

Comment: If you where using the local address 127.0.0 you are using IPv4 Yes

Comment: Well, thanks for the help.  Ping just returned "request timed out"

Comment: You are welcome. If the request timed out that means that ip address either does not exist or is not connected. Did you run the ip config on the second computer and retrieve the ipV4 address before pinging ?

Comment: No, but I will next time I have access.

Comment: Also, will his non public ip allow me to ping with a wireless connection?  This may be an issue with being connected to university Internet.  Maybe a security thing?

Comment: If you are using university internet you will need to check with them on security specifications for allowed ports and if they allow udp. If they allow udp you will need to make sure that the ports your are using for your client and server do not fall under the university block list